# How to catch a tcp packet in windows?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, windows-server-2003

I've got Windows 2003 server and i see in my firewall logs some denied tcp packets: about 1-5 per hour.

It looks like that:

18:20:37 tcp 192.168.xx.y(4994) -> 104.28.25.67(80), 1 packet 
18:39:15 tcp 192.168.xx.z(3823) -> 212.30.134.166(80), 1 packet 
18:39:36 tcp 192.168.xx.z(3842) -> 212.30.134.167(80), 1 packet

I think, that it is some windows process, may by Windows Update or some similar but i want to know exactly.

Tcpview can show process name and connection, but cannot log and it is impossible to looking at screen for some hours to catch this process.

Microsoft Network monitor not write the name of process or PID - only network connections.
Internal Firewall logging also do not write process name.

Who know software like tcpview, witch can do logging network packets and write the process name (PID) of outgoing connections?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like tcpvcon.exe can help )))
batch like that will show all connections:

:b1
echo.%date% %time% -----------"%temp%\tcp.log"
tcpvcon.exe -n -c >> "%temp%\tcp.log"
ping 127.0.0.0>nul
goto b1

Comment: can you show an example of the output? and he didn't ask just for PID with all connections he asked for that with the packets with those connections. He said TCPview doesn't do it and TCPvcon is the command line version.. so can you show in your answer some output that shows that it does it? I haven't tried with the switch you mention but this screenshot has it not showing packets http://img.informer.com/screenshots/103/103612_3.png

Comment: @barlop Did you not notice that this was a self-answer?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi I doubt I did notice it was a self answer, but the comment still applies. The question is the question. Though it does increase the likelyhood that it's a correct answer, it doesn't guarantee it or mean that the answer can't be improved. It's a QnA database site so an answer is there not just for the original questioner but to help others.